# Bootstrap is messing with my table layout when i use repeater

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, asprepeater, nested-repeater

I have a repeater with a couple nested repeaters. Everythink works fine, except for the layout when I try to use bootstrap. In the first picture

[image]

I try to make it work inside a div with class=row. Everything is crazy. Even when i try to have it alone second picture

[image]

same mistakes. When i remove all divs, the render is perfect. Here is my code for the first one

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="border-bottom:double;">
            <ul class="nav flex-column" style="margin-left: -15px;">
                (navigate menu)
            </ul>
            </div>
 <div  class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10"  style="border-bottom:double">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3">
    ... an invisibe panel...
</div>    
             <div class="col-12">
    ... panel with search option for populating repeater ...
</div>
                    <div class="col-12">

                <asp:Panel ID="panel_endiaferomenwn_provoli" runat="server">
                <div class="table-responsive table-bordered">
                        <table  style="min-width:950px; width:100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 8%; min-width:100px; text-wrap:none" id="last_change"><b>a</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 30%;"><b>b</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 15%;"><b>c</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 10%;"><b>d</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 14%;"><b>e / αγόρασε</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 10%; min-width:100px;"><b>f</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 8%; min-width:100px;"><b>g</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 5%; min-width:80px;"><b>h</b></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                <asp:Repeater ID="rep_all" runat="server" DataSourceID="data_rep" OnPreRender="rep_all_PreRender">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="table-responsive table-bordered">
                        <table style="min-width:950px; width:100%;">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:8%; min-width:100px;"><asp:Label ID="lbl_rep_last_change" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("date_of_last_change")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                <td style="width:30%;">
                                 <asp:Repeater ID="rep_details" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table style="width:100%">
                                                <thead>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                   <tr data-toggle="collapse" class="xeraki" style="width:30%;" data-target="#collapse<%# Eval("id") %>">
                                                        <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_name_title" Text="Επωνυμία" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></td>
                                                        <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_name" runat="server" Font-Underline="true" ForeColor="Blue" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                       <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        <div class="collapse" id="collapse<%# Eval("id") %>">
                                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table style="width:100%">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_til1_title" Text="Τηλ1 " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_til1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("phone1") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_til2_title" Text="Τηλ2 " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></td>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_til2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("phone2") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_manager_title" Text="Υπεύθυνος " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></td>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_manager" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("manager") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_perioxi_title" Text="Περιοχή " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></td>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_perioxi" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("area") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_address_title" Text="Διεύθυνση " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></td>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_address" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("address") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_afm_title" Text="ΑΦΜ " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></td>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_afm" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("afm") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_salesman_title" Text="Πωλητής " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></td>
                                                    <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_salesman" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("salesman") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>

                                    </ItemTemplate>                            
                                    </asp:Repeater>

                                </td>
                                <td style="width:15%;"><asp:Label ID="lbl_rep_show" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("show") %>'></asp:Label> <asp:Label ID="lbl_rep_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label> </td>
                                <td style="width:10%;"><asp:Label ID="lbl_rep_perioxi" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("area") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                <td style="width:14%;">
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="rep_rep_inter" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table>
                                                <thead>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border:none;padding:1px;width:55%;"><asp:Label ID="lbl2_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lbl_rep2_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label></td>
                                                    <td style="border:none;padding:1px;width:45%;"><asp:CheckBox CssClass="d-flex text-right" ID="check_buy" runat="server" Text="" Enabled="false" /></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>                            
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width:10%;min-width:100px;"><asp:Label ID="lbl_rep_katastasi" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("katastasi") %>'></asp:Label> </td>
                                <td style="width:8%;min-width:100px;"><asp:Label ID="lbl_rep_prothesmia" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("date_of_next_step")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                <td style="width: 5%; min-width:80px;">
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"">
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_expand" runat="server" OnClick="btn_expand_Click" ImageUrl="../webimages/expand-arrow.png" Width="48" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_collapse" runat="server" OnClick="btn_collapse_Click" ImageUrl="../webimages/collapse-arrow.png" Width="48" Visible="false"/>
                                        </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                                <tr>

                                    <div class="table-responsive table-bordered">
                                        <table style="min-width: 950px; width: 100%;">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>

                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>

                                        <div id="expand_epafes" runat="server" class="colapse">
                                            <header>
                                                <div class="table-responsive table-bordered">
                                                <table style="min-width: 950px; width: 100%;">

                                                 <tr>
                                                    <td style="width: 10%; min-width:175px;" id="date_epafes2"><b>Ημερομηνία Επαφής</b></td>
                                                    <td style="width: 45%; text-align:center;"><b>Παρατηρήσεις</b></td>
                                                     <td style="width:15%;"><b>Κατάσταση</b></td>
                                                     <td style="width:10%;"><b>Προθεσμία</b></td>
                                                     <td style="width: 15%;"><b>Προσφορά</b></td>
                                                    <td style="width: 5%; min-width:80px;"><b></b></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                  </table>
                                                    </div>
                                            </header>
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="rep_epafes" runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="table-responsive table-bordered">

                                                <table style="min-width: 950px; width: 100%;">

                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                           <td style="width: 10%; min-width:175px;" id="date_epafes">
                                                               <asp:Label ID="epafes_lbl_imerominia" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("date_made")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                               <asp:TextBox ID="epafes_edit_imerominia" runat="server" Visible="false" TextMode="Date" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("date_made")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                           </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 45%;">
                                                               <asp:Label ID="epafes_lbl_remarks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("remarks") %>' ></asp:Label>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_epafes_id_endiaferontos" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("id_endeiaferontos") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_epafes_id_epafis" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' ></asp:Label>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="epafes_edit_remarks" runat="server" CssClass="w-100" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("remarks") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 15%;">

                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 10%;">

                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 15%;">
                                                                <asp:Button ID="btn_test" runat="server" Text="test" OnClick="btn_test_Click"  />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 5%; min-width:80px;" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../webimages/edit.png" ID="btn_edit_edit" runat="server" OnClick="btn_edit_edit_Click" />
                                                                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../webimages/ok.png" ID="btn_edit_save" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="btn_edit_save_Click" />
                                                                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../webimages/cancel.png" ID="btn_edit_cancel" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="btn_edit_cancel_Click" />
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <div class="table-responsive table-bordered">
                                                <table style="min-width: 950px; width: 100%;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="width: 10%; min-width: 175px;">
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_epafes_date_add" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 50%;">
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_epafes_remarks_add" runat="server" Placeholder="Παρατηρήσεις" CssClass="w-100" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width:20%;">
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 15%;">

                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 5%; min-width: 80px;" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../webimages/save.png" ID="btn_epafi_add" runat="server" OnClick="btn_epafi_add_Click" />
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                       </div>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                        </table>
                            </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="data_rep" runat="server" (connectio details) ></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </asp:Panel>

                </div>

                </div>        
 </div>


        </div>


</div>
```

I am sorry for the long code, tried to make it shorter. I also include a picture with code collapsed, to help you see it easier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clean code will help a lot in knowing where you are at, I think you had an extra div element that wasn't suppost to be there:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="border-bottom:double;">
        <ul class="nav flex-column" style="margin-left: -15px;">
            (navigate menu)
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10" style="border-bottom:double">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                ... an invisibe panel...
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                ... panel with search option for populating repeater ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">

                <asp:Panel ID="panel_endiaferomenwn_provoli" runat="server">
                    <div class="table-responsive table-bordered">
                        <table style="min-width:950px; width:100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 8%; min-width:100px; text-wrap:none" id="last_change"><b>a</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 30%;"><b>b</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 15%;"><b>c</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 10%;"><b>d</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 14%;"><b>e / αγόρασε</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 10%; min-width:100px;"><b>f</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 8%; min-width:100px;"><b>g</b></td>
                                <td style="width: 5%; min-width:80px;"><b>h</b></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <asp:Repeater ID="rep_all" runat="server" DataSourceID="data_rep" OnPreRender="rep_all_PreRender">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="table-responsive table-bordered">
                                <table style="min-width:950px; width:100%;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width:8%; min-width:100px;">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_rep_last_change" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("date_of_last_change")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:30%;">
                                                <asp:Repeater ID="rep_details" runat="server">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                                            <table style="width:100%">
                                                                <thead>
                                                                </thead>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr data-toggle="collapse" class="xeraki" style="width:30%;" data-target="#collapse<%# Eval(" id ") %>">
                                                                        <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_name_title" Text="Επωνυμία" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_name" runat="server" Font-Underline="true" ForeColor="Blue" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;"></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="collapse" id="collapse<%# Eval(" id ") %>">
                                                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                                                <table style="width:100%">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_til1_title" Text="Τηλ1 " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_til1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("phone1") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_til2_title" Text="Τηλ2 " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_til2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("phone2") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_manager_title" Text="Υπεύθυνος " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_manager" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("manager") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_perioxi_title" Text="Περιοχή " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_perioxi" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("area") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_address_title" Text="Διεύθυνση " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_address" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("address") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_afm_title" Text="ΑΦΜ " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_afm" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("afm") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px; width: 40%; text-wrap: none;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_salesman_title" Text="Πωλητής " runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="border: none; padding: 1px;">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_det_salesman" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("salesman") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>

                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:Repeater>

                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:15%;">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_rep_show" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("show") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_rep_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_rep_perioxi" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("area") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:14%;">
                                                <asp:Repeater ID="rep_rep_inter" runat="server">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                                            <table>
                                                                <thead>
                                                                </thead>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td style="border:none;padding:1px;width:55%;">
                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl2_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_rep2_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="border:none;padding:1px;width:45%;">
                                                                            <asp:CheckBox CssClass="d-flex text-right" ID="check_buy" runat="server" Text="" Enabled="false" />
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:Repeater>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:10%;min-width:100px;">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_rep_katastasi" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("katastasi") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:8%;min-width:100px;">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_rep_prothesmia" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("date_of_next_step")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 5%; min-width:80px;">
                                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" ">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_expand " runat="server " OnClick="btn_expand_Click " ImageUrl="../webimages/expand-arrow.png " Width="48 " />
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_collapse " runat="server " OnClick="btn_collapse_Click " ImageUrl="../webimages/collapse-arrow.png " Width="48 " Visible="false "/>
                                    </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <div class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
                                    <table style="min-width: 950px; width: 100%; ">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>

                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                                    <div id="expand_epafes " runat="server " class="colapse ">
                                        <header>
                                            <div class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
                                            <table style="min-width: 950px; width: 100%; ">

                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 10%; min-width:175px; " id="date_epafes2 "><b>Ημερομηνία Επαφής</b></td>
                                                <td style="width: 45%; text-align:center; "><b>Παρατηρήσεις</b></td>
                                                 <td style="width:15%; "><b>Κατάσταση</b></td>
                                                 <td style="width:10%; "><b>Προθεσμία</b></td>
                                                 <td style="width: 15%; "><b>Προσφορά</b></td>
                                                <td style="width: 5%; min-width:80px; "><b></b></td>
                                            </tr>

                                              </table>
                                                </div>
                                        </header>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rep_epafes " runat="server ">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="table-responsive table-bordered ">

                                            <table style="min-width: 950px; width: 100%; ">

                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                       <td style="width: 10%; min-width:175px; " id="date_epafes ">
                                                           <asp:Label ID="epafes_lbl_imerominia " runat="server " Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("date_made ")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy ") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                           <asp:TextBox ID="epafes_edit_imerominia " runat="server " Visible="false " TextMode="Date " Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("date_made ")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd ") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                       </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 45%; ">
                                                           <asp:Label ID="epafes_lbl_remarks " runat="server " Text='<%# Eval("remarks ") %>' ></asp:Label>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_epafes_id_endiaferontos " runat="server " Visible="false " Text='<%# Eval("id_endeiaferontos ") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_epafes_id_epafis " runat="server " Visible="false " Text='<%# Eval("id ") %>' ></asp:Label>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="epafes_edit_remarks " runat="server " CssClass="w-100 " Visible="false " Text='<%# Eval("remarks ") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 15%; ">

                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 10%; ">

                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 15%; ">
                                                            <asp:Button ID="btn_test " runat="server " Text="test " OnClick="btn_test_Click "  />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 5%; min-width:80px; " class="d-flex justify-content-center ">
                                                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../webimages/edit.png " ID="btn_edit_edit " runat="server " OnClick="btn_edit_edit_Click " />
                                                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../webimages/ok.png " ID="btn_edit_save " runat="server " Visible="false " OnClick="btn_edit_save_Click " />
                                                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../webimages/cancel.png " ID="btn_edit_cancel " runat="server " Visible="false " OnClick="btn_edit_cancel_Click " />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        <div class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
                                            <table style="min-width: 950px; width: 100%; ">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="width: 10%; min-width: 175px; ">
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_epafes_date_add " runat="server " TextMode="Date " Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd ") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 50%; ">
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_epafes_remarks_add " runat="server " Placeholder="Παρατηρήσεις " CssClass="w-100 " ></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width:20%; ">
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 15%; ">

                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width: 5%; min-width: 80px; " class="d-flex justify-content-center ">
                                                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../webimages/save.png " ID="btn_epafi_add " runat="server " OnClick="btn_epafi_add_Click " />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                                   </div>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                        </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="data_rep " runat="server " (connectio details) ></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </asp:Panel>


        </div>  

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the layout. Make use of style="display-flex". Put it in a columns parent division along with subdivisions. col-6 or whatever append it to that div(Parent you can give col-12). Your formatting will be maintained. Happy coding :)